# Comment-Meta doesn't work with latest wordpress update

Tags: comments, metabox, comment-meta

I already had this script working, but since the last update of the wordpress core it doesn't save the comment-meta anymore.

```
/**
 * Comments Winner
 */

// Add new heading to comments tables
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', 'winner_comment_column' );
function winner_comment_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['winning_comment'] = __( '(lieb)gewonnen' );
    return $columns;
}

// Print comment meta for new meta column
add_action( 'manage_comments_custom_column', 'myplugin_comment_column', 10, 2 );
function myplugin_comment_column( $column, $comment_ID ) {
    if ( 'winning_comment' != $column )
        return;
    echo esc_attr( get_comment_meta( $comment_ID, 'winning_comment', true ) );
}

// Replace the quickedit action to call an additional expandedOpen function
add_filter( 'comment_row_actions', 'my_quick_edit_action', 10, 2 );
function my_quick_edit_action( $actions, $comment ) {
    global $post;
    $actions['quickedit'] = '<a onclick="commentReply.close();if( typeof(expandedOpen) == \'function\' ) expandedOpen('.$comment->comment_ID.');commentReply.open( \''.$comment->comment_ID.'\',\''.$post->ID.'\',\'edit\' );return false;" class="vim-q" title="'.esc_attr__( 'Quick Edit' ).'" href="#">' . __( 'Quick Edit' ) . '</a>';
    return $actions;
}

// Add some javscript into the footer for the edit comments page
add_action('admin_footer-edit-comments.php', 'edit_winning_comment_ajax');
function edit_winning_comment_ajax() {

    // Create nonce
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'my_cmeta' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function expandedOpen(id) {
        // Pull the data from the new column and pass that along to our new input
        var mv = jQuery('tr#comment-'+id+' .column-winning_comment').text() || '';
        if ( mv == "gewonnen" ) {
            jQuery('#comment-meta-winner').attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            jQuery('#comment-meta-winner').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }
    function saveCommentMeta() {
        // Build the data object for the ajax action setup to update comment meta
        var cid = jQuery('#comment_ID').val() || 0;
        var mv  = jQuery('#comment-meta-winner').val() || '';
        var data = {
            action: "update_winning_comment",
            _ajax_nonce: "<?php echo $nonce; ?>",
            comment_ID: cid,
            comment_metaKey: 'winning_comment',
            comment_metaValue: mv
        };
        // Post data to ajax
        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if( 'success' != response )
                return;
            // Valid response, update the new table column(so you don't need to refresh)
            jQuery('tr#comment-'+cid+' .column-winning_comment').text(mv);
            // Close the quickedit
            commentReply.close();
        });
    };
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Setup ajax callback for the new action
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_winning_comment', 'update_winning_comment_ajax' );
function update_winning_comment_ajax() {

    // Check nonce
    check_ajax_referer( 'my_cmeta' );
    // Check expected fields are there
    foreach( array( 'comment_ID', 'comment_metaKey', 'comment_metaValue' ) as $field )
        if( !isset( $_POST[$field] ) )
            die;

    // Validate ID
    $commentID  = absint( $_POST['comment_ID'] );
    if( !$commentID )
        die;

    // Validate meta key
    $commentKey = sanitize_title( $_POST['comment_metaKey'] );
    if( empty( $commentKey ) )
        die;

    // Validate meta value(or empty)
    $commentVal = sanitize_title( $_POST['comment_metaValue'] );

    // Update meta 
    update_comment_meta( $commentID, $commentKey, $commentVal );

    // Success response
    echo 'success';// Echoed value is received as the response
    // And die, expected behaviour for ajax actions
    die;
}

// Run filter on the comment reply box(necessary to add new fields into the quickedit box)
add_filter( 'wp_comment_reply', 'wr_editComment_menu', 10, 2 );
function wr_editComment_menu($str, $input) {

    extract( $input );
    $table_row = true;

    if ( $mode == 'single' )
        $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Post_Comments_List_Table');
    else 
        $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Comments_List_Table');

    // Get editor string
    ob_start();
        $quicktags_settings = array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' );
    wp_editor( '', 'replycontent', array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => false, 'quicktags' => $quicktags_settings, 'tabindex' => 104 ) );
    $editorStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Get nonce string
    ob_start();    
    wp_nonce_field( "replyto-comment", "_ajax_nonce-replyto-comment", false );
        if ( current_user_can( "unfiltered_html" ) )
        wp_nonce_field( "unfiltered-html-comment", "_wp_unfiltered_html_comment", false );
    $nonceStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $content = '<form method="get" action="">';
    if ( $table_row ) :
        $content .= '<table style="display:none;"><tbody id="com-reply"><tr id="replyrow" style="display:none;"><td colspan="'.$wp_list_table->get_column_count().'" class="colspanchange">';
    else :
        $content .= '<div id="com-reply" style="display:none;"><div id="replyrow" style="display:none;">';
    endif;

    $content .= '
            <div id="replyhead" style="display:none;"><h5>Reply to Comment</h5></div>
            <div id="addhead" style="display:none;"><h5>Add new Comment</h5></div>
            <div id="edithead" style="display:none;">';

    $content .= '  
                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="author" style="margin:0 5px;">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="newcomment_author" size="50" value="" tabindex="101" id="author" />
                </div>

                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="author-email" style="margin:0 5px;">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="newcomment_author_email" size="50" value="" tabindex="102" id="author-email" />
                </div>

                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="author-url" style="margin:0 5px;">URL</label>
                    <input type="text" id="author-url" name="newcomment_author_url" size="103" value="" tabindex="103" />
                </div>';

    // Add new quick edit fields       
    $content .= '
                <div class="inside">
                    <label for="comment-meta-winner" style="margin:0 5px; position:relative; top:2px;">Gewonnen</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="comment-meta-winner" name="comment-meta-winner" value="gewonnen" style="width:auto; margin-top:5px;" />
                    <!--<a onclick="saveCommentMeta();" class="button-secondary save-mycustommeta" href="#">'.__( 'Save' ).'</a>-->
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both;"></div>

            </div>';

    // Add editor
    $content .= "<div id='replycontainer'>\n";   
    $content .= $editorStr;
    $content .= "</div>\n";  

    $content .= '          
            <p id="replysubmit" class="submit">
            <a href="#comments-form" class="cancel button-secondary alignleft" tabindex="107">Cancel</a>
            <a onclick="saveCommentMeta();" href="#comments-form" class="save button-primary alignright" tabindex="106">
            <span id="addbtn" style="display:none;">Add Comment</span>
            <span id="savebtn" style="display:none;">Update Comment</span>
            <span id="replybtn" style="display:none;">Submit Reply</span></a>
            <img class="waiting" style="display:none;" src="'.esc_url( admin_url( "images/wpspin_light.gif" ) ).'" alt="" />
            <span class="error" style="display:none;"></span>
            <br class="clear" />
            </p>';

        $content .= '
            <input type="hidden" name="user_ID" id="user_ID" value="'.get_current_user_id().'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_ID" id="comment_ID" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" id="comment_post_ID" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" value="'.$position.'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="';

    if ( $checkbox ) $content .= '1'; else $content .=  '0';
    $content .= "\" />\n";
        $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" id="mode" value="'.esc_attr( $mode ).'" />';

    $content .= $nonceStr;
    $content .="\n";

    if ( $table_row ) :
        $content .= '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    else :
        $content .= '</div></div>';
    endif;
    $content .= "\n</form>\n";
    return $content;
}

?>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this wouldn't work. The additinal checkbox in the comments-menu appears, however when trying to save it, it doesn't work. The comment-meta doesn't get stored in the db.

Kind Regards,
Matt

Comment: what does `update_comment_meta()` returns?

Comment: Well, the problem is, that the the console says `saveCommentMeta()` is not defined? This is my problem in the first place.

Comment: Try to replace the action `admin_footer-edit-comments.php` with for example `admin_footer`, to test if the action is too restrict for your setup.

Comment: No, doesn't change anyhting. My function `saveCommentMeta()`is called if I try and add a `console.log(test)` to it. So when clicking on update in the comments-quickedit the test appears in my console. However nothing is saved.

Comment: In the function your ajax calls (`update_winning_comment_ajax()`), assign `update_comment_meta( $commentID, $commentKey, $commentVal );` to a variable and return it's value. Subsequently `console.log()` it out to see what it is. At least that way we can determine if it's failing on the update and work our way backwards

Comment: That code generates a lot of `Notice`s when I try to run it. Enable debugging, clean that up, and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: Where is `ajaxurl` set?

Comment: `_get_list_table()` is a private function. That might not be working.